# Bootstrap modal popup for ActionLink not showing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a **Create New** form-link on my Students page to create a new Student which I want to show up as modal popup using bootstrap, instead of going to another page and creating the student.

It is currently working as a Html.ActionLink, but I am having difficulty in showing the form in the body of the popup. I later also want to use it to insert the data with AJAX, but want to implement the modal popup first.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <p class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @id = "create" })

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Create Modal</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @id = "create" })

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" >Create</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
```

**Create Action in StudentController**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate, PaymentDue")]
           Student student)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    studentRepository.InsertStudent(student);
                    studentRepository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble because you want to put a form inside a modal but instead you have put an action link to another page which has a form on it. You have to copy the form off of the page you don't want and paste it inside the body of your modal. then when you submit the form here it will hit the action that your form points to in your controller and the action will handle the form data and return a view aka refresh the page. So you should edit your form action to do a redirect to the index view or watever view it is that has this modal on it.  as you said you are thinking of using ajax, probably because you don't want the page to refresh. Anyway i will make a mock form here as i do not know what your form looks like or your HttpPost action. P.s. I'm typing on a phone.

Just start again.

```
  // here is a button which will open up the modal.  forget about using an actionlink to do this.
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  data-toggle="modal" data- target="#myModal">Create New</button>

  //here is a functioning modal
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Create Something</h4>
        </div> 
        //wrap your modal-body and your modal- footer in a form. You can copy the begin form from  your other page. You may have problems here  because if this is a scaffolded crud that form most  likely uses another model(not modal) which you  return to it from an action. What you can do is  make an html form and name your inputs correctly  and post it to your action.

        <form action="/ControllerName/ActionName" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          First name: <input type="text" name="fname">     <br>
          Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>           
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right"  value="Save">          
    </div>
    </form>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

The submit input will submit your form and do a post to the action you have specified in the url. This is in essence the same as writting:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {

      <div class="modal-body">
         First name: <input type="text" name="fname">     <br>
         Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>           
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success  pull-right"  value="Save">       
  </div>

 }
```

I do not know if you require a validation summary or an anti forgery token. You have to check thr form you wish to copy.

Then your action would look something like this:

```
public class ControllerName : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Add action logic here
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionName(string fname, string lname)
    {
        // do something with fname and lname. Thenaming of your html inputs and the parameters you recieve here are important. If the post action has a required parameter that you do not post it will give you a 404 or something.

        //redirec to whatever page has the modal on
        return View("Index")
     }       
 }
```

Answer Edits:

So for you situation I would recommend forget about passing back a model for the create form. The reason it returns a model to the create page is that if a person fills out the form and there is an error with the save the action will return the object with all the fields that the user filled out so that he doesnt have to fill the all out again. You can see this in the HttpPost action for the form. When you are initially creating an entry you do not need a model though because you start with all the fields as empty anyway. (FYI - You should realize the obvious need for returning a model to an "edit" page  though because you are editing values which have already been saved in your db..) So it is your choice - if you want to return the fields which have been filled out back to the page if the save fails you are going to have to use a view model. Otherwise you can just make a standard html form and post that to yout action. I can do an example of that here.

Here is your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <div class="modal-body">
         First name: <input type="text" name="FirstMidName">     <br>
         Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>           
         //do you need a date picker here????
         Enrollment Date: <input type="text" name="EnrollmentDate"><br>

        Payment Due: <input type="text" name="PaymentDue"><br>

       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success  pull-right"  value="Save">       
  </div>

 }
```

Here is your controller:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Create(string LastName, string FirstMidName, string EnrollmentDate, string PaymentDue)
    {

       // If you do not have validation on the front end you at tge very least need to put some null checks here based on you required fields. I remover the model state check as we are not passing through a model anymore. So:
        if (FirstMidName != ""){
        try
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.LastName = LastName;
            student.FirstMidName = FirstMidName;

           //you need to handle how this date is parsed here
            student.EnrollmentDate =DateTime.Parse(EnrollmentDate);

            //if this is a bool you may need to do some logic here depending on what values your form gives you. Maybe if (PaymentDue == "checked"){student.PaymentDue = true} else { student.PaymentDue = false}
          //if payment due is monetry value you must be very catefull about the way you parse decimals/floats with the decimal point and culturr information. You will need to do some research here.
   student.PaymentDue = PaymentDue;

                studentRepository.InsertStudent(student);
                studentRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
        }
        }
        //see i removed the old return view with a model here which was incase there was a problem saving.
        return RedirectToAction("Index") ;
    }
```

Thats a rough idea. im typin on my phone lol. I would recommend copy all the validation elements from your exsisting create form and paste them into your new form modal, including the validation summary if there is one. You can open up your existing form in chrome and right click to view page source and then copy the rendered html for the form from there so that you dont loose any of the existing validation and inputs. But keep the @html.Beginform and the antiforgerytoken if you like. Alyernatively you shoild use a view model which im not gling to type out now!!

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am very new to jQuery and AJAX and I am trying to get my head around it. If I need to use jQuery to create the modal popup, will it change the format of how you laid it out in your post?

Comment: No, just as long as you have the form set up correctly on the page it does not matter if you use jquery or default bootstrap. however i would recommend using the default bootstrap modal, it works fine. Also note that i have edited the close button on the modal because buttons that you put in a form will do a submit. So I will change it to an anchortag.

Comment: As you mentioned, it is giving me issues in using the begin form in the modal body section as I cannot use more than one model reference in the View. When I try to create a normal html form, I am having trouble creating the validator or AntiForgery.

Comment: Okay you have some options here. Don't worry its defanetly possible changes to do. The first option you may want to consider is using a View Model. Do you know what a view model is? If you are developing with mvc you are going to have to learn because you will run into this again. A view model allows you to return two or more models to a view and whatever other data you would like to return. For a create though, especially in this fashion,  you do not need to return a model for the form. I will type some edits in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the JS hooks and the Bootstrap button classes to a `p` tag, which is not supported by either. Your link should have these instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { id = "create", @class = "btn btn-primary", data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#myModal" })
```

Comment: Thanks, It is showing the popup box now. But it is showing the full `nav-bar` of the site and not showing the 'X' for the close option in the header, nor the `cancel` button in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a button to get your modal. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>`, and if you want the button to appear like a action link you can do it by css.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *Jquery* to open modal popup

*JS*

```
$(function () {
            $('#create').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

*HTML*

```
<body>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { @id = "create" })

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Create Modal</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```